# Not translating key on model define

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, i18next

#### Problem

Using **18next.t** function to translate key, getting me the key instead translated key value

#### Environment

sequelize@5.22.4

i18next@21.3.3

#### Model definition `candidate.js`

```js
...
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Candidate = sequelize.define('Candidate', {
    status: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM,
      values: [
        ...
      ],
    },
    type: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM,
      values: [types.CANDIDATE, types.EMPLOYEE],
      validate: {
        isIn: {
          args: [allowedTypes],
          msg: i18next.t('candidate-invalid-type', { allowedTypes, joinArrays: ', ' })
...
```

#### Result:

`candidate-invalid-type`

#### Expected:

`{Custom error message located on lang.json}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that i'm found was on languages delay load

So i choosed to use sequelize model field property msg as [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) propertie

It worked like a charm

Replace

`msg: i18next.t('candidate-invalid-type', { allowedTypes, joinArrays: ', ' })`

For

`get msg() { return i18next.t('candidate-invalid-type', { allowedTypes, joinArrays: ', ' })}`

Complete code snippet

```js
...
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Candidate = sequelize.define('Candidate', {
    status: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM,
      values: [
        ...
      ],
    },
    type: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM,
      values: [types.CANDIDATE, types.EMPLOYEE],
      validate: {
        isIn: {
          args: [allowedTypes],
          get msg() { return i18next.t('candidate-invalid-type', { allowedTypes, joinArrays: ', ' })}
...
```